# PHPWebSocket as a singleton

Tags: php, websocket

What is the proper way of launching a PHPWebSocket so that there is only one instance and there's no need to launch it separatedly from apache itself (a.k.a. no open terminal and "php websocket.php"). I am using CodeIgniter, in case that helps.

Comment: The proper way is not to use singleton. **Ever !**

Comment: So everytime I load the page I create a new instance? How do I fire up one somehow integrated with apache, so I can forget about launching it separatedly?